# which SQL Server Product I shall install?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, windows-xp, installation

I want to Learn SSIS package in windows XP system, which edition of SQL Server shall I install?

I have downloaded the SQL Server 2008R2, but failed installed, the error message saying:

SQL Server 2008R2 setup100.exe and setuppatch.exe canot be run in this mode. if you are running setup100.exe,
start setup.exe instead....

Thanks,
Ling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows XP is not a windows server system, so you can only install sql server developer edition that has the same functionality as enterprise edition but the license is limited to development purpose.

Comment: oops, sorry, I made a mistake. sql server 2008 standard edition can be installed on Win XP... But I think developer edition is better for you and it's ~$50 on Microsoft Store.

Comment: Thanks Ricky, I am currently downloaded a couple editions of SQL Server, but seems only express works, but not supports the SSIS. I will do more research on this. Thanks for your kind help. I will have a try.

Answer (score 1):

There is the [software and hardware reqiurements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) for SQL Server 2008 R2, and there is the [feature supported by Editions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993%28v=sql.100%29.aspx). Using these resources you can select appropriate edition for you.